# How to correctly crop image blob using layout dimensions?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

What is the correct method to crop an image captured using the camera to match what the user can view within an overlay that exposes a portion of the screen.

I am using an overlay with showcamera to capture my image.

The transparent overlay has a label across the top, and a view about halfway down the screen (top:315) - so the camera is exposed between the label and view. (see below)

```
<View class="overlay">
    <!-- this view is transparent -->
    <View id="View_title_area">
        <!-- view height 50 / white background -->
        <Label id="Label_title" class="page_title"  text="Take Photo"/>  
    </View> 

    <!-- Camera is displayed here -->
    <!-- Camera is displayed here -->
    <!-- Camera is displayed here -->
    <!-- Camera is displayed here -->

    <View id="View_control_area">
        <!-- view top=315 -->
        <Label id="Label_instruction" text="{image_aspect_instruction}" />              
        <Button id="Button_capture" class="button_white" onClick="Button_capture_onClick"  title=" Take Photo " />
    </View>             
</View>
```

Then I am cropping the image using showCamera, success: function() like this...

```
var device_width = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;

var camera_height =  Math.round((camera_width/4)*3);  

var newblob = e.media.imageAsCropped({x: 0, y:51, width : device_width, height : 215 });

$.imagetest.image = newblob;
```

I realize the basic issue is the camera is capturing an image @ 2448w x 3264h and I am using dpi layout dimensions to crop the image. How should this be done?

```
[INFO] :   Ti.Platform.displayCaps.density: xhigh
[INFO] :   Ti.Platform.displayCaps.dpi: 480
[INFO] :   Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight: 736
[INFO] :   Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth: 414
[INFO] :   Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor: 3
```

Comment: hey, did you got any luck with this ? i have the same problem..

Comment: no. maybe we should work this out together.